# Apparent Division Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't understand the division result I see in the following code.

The first column yields 40.

The second column yields 53.

The third column is simply dividing 40 by 53, which should come up to 0.7547169811, but instead, the decimal is one place further to the right.

What is causing this behavior, and how should I correct it?

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM students s
    INNER JOIN ~[temp.table.current.selection:students] stusel ON stusel.dcid=s.dcid 
    WHERE s.lunchstatus = 'F'),

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ~[temp.table.current.selection:students]),

(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM students s
    INNER JOIN ~[temp.table.current.selection:students] stusel ON stusel.dcid=s.dcid 
    WHERE s.lunchstatus = 'F') 
    /
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ~[temp.table.current.selection:students])

)

---
40    53    7.54716981132075471698113207547169811321E-01
```

Comment: See that E at the end? Google scientific notation. It is moving the decimal 1 spot to the left, therefore giving you .75 as a result

Comment: See the 'E-01' after the number. It *is* 0.754

Comment: Hey, we're programmers, not mathematicians!

Comment: 'Why is there an e in my number?' on Google gives you the answer.

Comment: Also, which client are you seeing this in? I think there was a version of SQL Developer that used to show E notation a lot (current version doesn't seem to, and I may be misremembering), but it could still be overridden. Other clients will have their own defaults.

Comment: I was seeing it inside a web based application called PowerSchool. The sql is passed down to the database through a Tomcat / javascript layer before being displayed on-screen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's scientific notation - try casting your result to, for example, a decimal:

```
select
    cast((40 / 53) as decimal(5, 4)) as DIVISION_RESULT
from
    dual
```

Just be aware that by doing so, you risk a loss of floating point precision.

Answer (score 2):

It shows `7.54716981132075471698113207547169811321E-01`
 which means `0.754716981132075471698113207547169811321`. Check out the [wikipedia article on E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation).